# Banach fixed point theorem with partial averaging

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces, fixed-point-theorems

Let $X$ be a Banach space, and let $T : X \to X$ be $\alpha$-Lipschitz for $\alpha < 1$. Let $z_*$ be the fixed point of $T$. Suppose $\{\gamma_t\}_{t=1}^\infty$ be such that $0 < \gamma_t < 1$ for all $t$ and $\sum_t \gamma_t = \infty$. Let $x_0 \in X$ be arbitrary, and for $t \geq 1$, let $x_t = (1 - \gamma_t) x_{t-1} + \gamma_t T x_{t-1}$. Does it hold that $x_t \to z_*$?

Comment: What have you tried?  Can you offer some context?  For a fixed $\gamma$, the answer is clear, which only leaves the question whether or not $\sum_{t = 1}^{\infty} \gamma_{t} = \infty$ is the "right" condition.  But we could just as well replace it with some other condition --- so why that one?

Comment: It is the relevant analagous condition to the Monro-Robbins stochastic convergence conditions in this context, and seems eminently plausible to me: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stochastic_approximation . I was thinking about it while reading this paper, and the solution did not immediately spring to mind: https://www.mit.edu/~jnt/Papers/J089-02-jnt-optimistic.pdf . I've tried to write $d(x_i, x_{i-1})$ in terms of $d(x_{i-1}, x_{i-2})$ using the convexity of the metric and the contraction property, but haven't been able to come up with anything useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The condition $\sum_t \gamma_t = \infty$ is both necessary and sufficient. To see necessity, take $Tx = \alpha x$ for $0 < \alpha < 1$.

For sufficiency, first observe that for any $x \in X$, $\|Tx - z_*\| = \|Tx - Tz_*\| \leq \alpha \|x - z_*\|$. Now, for $t \geq 1$, note that
$$\|x_t - z_*\| = \|(1 - \gamma_t) x_{t-1} + \gamma_t T x_{t-1} - z_*\| \leq (1 - \gamma_t) \|x_{t-1} - z_*\| + \gamma_t \|T x_{t-1} - z_*\|$$
$$\leq (1 - \gamma_t) \|x_{t-1} - z_*\| + \gamma_t \alpha \|x_{t-1} - z_*\| = {\big (}1 - (1 - \alpha) \gamma_t{\big )} \|x_{t-1} - z_*\|.$$
By induction, we obtain
$$\|x_t - z_*\| \leq {\Big (}\prod\limits_{i=1}^t {\big (} 1 - (1 - \alpha) \gamma_i {\big )} {\Big )} \|x_0 - z_*\|.$$
This product converges to $0$ so long as $\sum_i \gamma_i = \infty$.